# Effect on the minimum distance of a code if we remove some rows/ column in its matrices

Tags: matrices, coding-theory

Suppose you are given a linear code with generator matrix $G$ and parity check
matrix $H$. The following is a list of ways you might modify your code. For
each, determine the possible effect on the minimum distance.

1. Remove a row from $G$.
2. Remove a row from $H$.
3. Remove a column from $G$.
4. Perform elementary row operations on $H$.

My understanding is that:

1. Removing a row from $G$ --> reducing the dimension $k$ --> possibly increase/decrease the min distance, but not sure if increasing or decreasing.
2. Same as 1
3. Removing a column from $G$ --> decreasing the length $n$ of the codewords --> decreasing the weight of codewords --> decreasing min distance $d$.
4. Performing elementary row operations on $H$ --> we get the equivalent $H'$ --> nothing changes --> not affecting the min distance.

Can anyone please point out if I am wrong or add more comments? Thanks.

Comment: If you remove a row from $G$, the code you end up with is a subset of the code you started with. Therefore you can say more. OTOH if you remove a row from $H$, you remove a parity check equation. Therefore the code you started with is a subset of the one you end up with. Again, you can say a bit more. You are on the right track abou the effect of removing a column. But it is possible that the removed bit was zero (at least on some words). Your answer to part 4 is correct.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, Jyrki Lahtonen. Would you mind explain why the subset of the original code might have bigger minimum distance? I've been thinking about that but cannot convince myself just yet.

Comment: Hint: consider the $[3,2]$ code with generator matrix $$G = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 1& 1\\0 & 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right].$$ What is its minimum distance? What is the minimum distance of the subcode when the second row is removed? When the first row is removed? Repeat for the case $$G = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 1& 0\\0 & 1 & 1\end{matrix}\right].$$

Comment: also just by logic, going to a subset can never decrease the minimum distance but can increase it if codewords which were part of a pair giving the minimum distance are all removed